# Set sheetsarray based on cell values

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering if it is possible to set an Array based on cell values from different sheets. For example, I've got a document where I'm first renaming the sheets based on their value in "C3"

```
Sub rename()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Sheets
        On Error Resume Next
        ws.Name = ws.Range("C3")
    Next ws

End Sub
```

After that, I create an new document and loop through each of the "old" sheets to search for specific values. But since I know how the Sheets are named, my range and other settings look like this

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim resultrange As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim sheetsArray As Sheets
Set sheetsArray = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Array("10", "20", "30", "40", "50"))

Dim target As Range
Dim sheetObject As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row
```

I'm a Little bit worried regarding the code below, since now I knew how the Sheets are named.

```
Set sheetsArray = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Array("10", "20", "30", "40", "50"))
```

So my question here, is it possible to set an Array without knowing how the sheets are named? Or is it possible to give a range based on the Name in a cell value?

I hope I could express my question understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the worksheet indices in the array.  They will not change unless the order of the worksheets change.

[image]